# A Star algorithm initial F-Value

Tags: algorithm, a-star

I've read lots of articles on the A Star algorithm which say that the F-Value for the initial node should be zero. I don't see why this is. I thought the F-value was the sum of the G-Value and the H-Value, so I would have thought that the initial F-Value should be 0 for the G-Value (distance of start from start) plus the H-Value (the heuristic distance to the goal).

It probably doesn't matter practically because if the initial node is taken from the priority queue and found to be the goal, its F-Value is irrelevant. However, I like to be thorough. Which is correct please, 0 for F-Value of the initial node, or whatever its H-Value is?

Comment: I guess you are right, but since the first node is usually also the only node in the heap and to be removed in the very first iteration, it does not really matter. Btw, do you have a reference? E.g. the pseudocode on Wikipedia does use `h` for `f` of the initial node.

Comment: Given that it takes time to compute the heuristic, why bother computing it when the initial node is the only node in the queue. The F-Value is only useful for ordering nodes in the queue. In other words, while it's technically correct to compute F = G+H for the initial node, there is no benefit to compute H, but there is a cost to compute H. So why do it?

Comment: @user3386109 I agree that it's not essential from an operational point of view, but in an educational context these details are important, and if an exception to an otherwise general rule is to be made, I think it's worth highlighting.